# MongoDB - projection of all array element match a query

Tags: mongodb, projection

Suppose I have the following set of documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

How can I query to retrieve documents that contain grades greater than 80, including the grades array with only the items matched in the query? Given the above example, I'd like to retrieve the following result set:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 87, 90 ] } // 70 is missing
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 85, 80 ] } // 79 is missing
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        // Emit a new document for each grade in the "grades" field
        "$unwind" : "$grades"
    },
    {
        // Only emit documents whose "grades" field is at least 80
        "$match" : {
            "grades" : {
                "$gte" : 80
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // Group documents back together by original _id
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "semester": {$first: "$semester"},
            "grades" : {
                "$push" : "$grades"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: If you had a really large collection, you might want to consider doing a match first to reduce the collection size, though you'd then need to do a second match.

Comment: Thank you. If I'd like to use it as a query for map-reduce how can it be done?